# Make a window without using class System.Windows.Forms.Form?

Tags: c#, windows, forms, system

**Make a window without using class System.Windows.Forms.Form?**

Continuing from one of my previous questions, how would I achieve this?
Would I just draw to the screen? Is it hard?

Comment: You can do this by adding references to some windows APIs (like RegisterClassEx and CreateWindowEx)

Comment: Yes, it is hard.  No point trying this until you've at least read Petzold's Programming Windows front to back twice.

Comment: Why do you want/need to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You avoid the Windows Forms class you mentioned, and just use [System.Windows.Window](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.window.aspx) (which is the WPF window) to create a Window without the Windows Forms classes - but I suspect this isn't the answer you are after...

Window creation is typically done by using the Windows API - Windows Forms (and WPF's main window) wrap the [Windows API calls](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff468925%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to create a window (ie: [CreateWindowEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632680%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)).  You could, of course, P/Invoke these calls yourself if you chose, but there really is no reason to do this.